# Using for loops only to iterate through an array of objects with other arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object

```
const bankAccounts = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Susan",
    balance: 100.32,
    deposits: [150, 30, 221],
    withdrawals: [110, 70.68, 120],
  },
  { id: 2, name: "Morgan", balance: 1100.0, deposits: [1100] },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Joshua",
    balance: 18456.57,
    deposits: [4000, 5000, 6000, 9200, 256.57],
    withdrawals: [1500, 1400, 1500, 1500],
  },
  { id: 4, name: "Candy", balance: 0.0 },
  { id: 5, name: "Phil", balance: 18, deposits: [100, 18], withdrawals: [100] },
];

function getClientsWithWrongBalance(bankAccounts) {
  const newArray = [];
  for (let obj of bankAccounts) {
    let sum = 0;
    if (obj.deposits) {
      for (let numDep of obj.deposits) {
        sum += numDep;
      }
    }
    if (obj.withdrawls) {
      for (let numWith of obj.withdrawls) {
        sum += numWith;
      }
    }
  }
  return newArray;
}
```

I have five bank accounts (objects) in the bankAccounts (array) variable. What I am trying to do is use for loops only to iterate through each account (object) and add up all the deposits elements and all the withdrawals elements, then I need to subtract the withdrawal from the deposit and see if it equals the balance key value pair of the accounts (object). I get stuck with my code when I can only add all of the elements of the deposits and withdrawals array's up. I do not know how to proceed. I have just messed around and tried different blocks of code. But I cannot figure out what to do.

Comment: why can you only add them? just subtract the withdrawals instead of adding them? `sum -= numWith;` and then compare it to the balance `const result = sum === obj.balance;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function getClientsWithWrongBalance(bankAccounts) {
  const newArray = [];
  for (let obj of bankAccounts) {
    let dsum = 0;
    let wsum = 0;
    if (obj.deposits) {
      for (let numDep of obj.deposits) {
        dsum += numDep;
      }
    }
    if (obj.withdrawals) {
      for (let numWith of obj.withdrawals) {
        wsum += numWith;
      }
    }
    if (Math.abs(obj.balance - dsum + wsum) > Number.EPSILON) {
      newArray.push(obj);
    }
  }
  return newArray;
}
```

Total deposits and withdrawals separately, compare to balance, and save any differences in the array returned.

As mentioned in comments, floating point isn't safe for money. You may represent money more safely by storing as integers and dividing to display. E.g. for $100 USD store as 10000 and `/100` to print.

Comment: So this is correct. Instead though in the last if statement, I used obj.balance != (dsum - wsum)) and I was able to resolve what I needed.

Comment: Right you are, thanks. Updated.

Comment: I think a better solution would be `if (obj.balance - dsum + wsum < Number.EPSILON)`. It's never a good idea to compare the result of a sum. And more in general, JavaScript and floating points shouldn't be used for accounting :)

Comment: typical example: `balance: 0.3, deposits: [0.1, 0.2]`, this will result as a wrong balance when it's not

Comment: @ChristianVincenzoTraina Thanks for the tip of Number.EPSILON

Answer (score 1):

Using Number.EPSILON to avoid floating point issues, credit to Christian

```js
const bankAccounts = [{"id":1,"name":"Susan","balance":100.32,"deposits":[150,30,221],"withdrawals":[110,70.68,120]},{"id":2,"name":"Morgan","balance":1100,"deposits":[1100]},{"id":3,"name":"Joshua","balance":18456.57,"deposits":[4000,5000,6000,9200,256.57],"withdrawals":[1500,1400,1500,1500]},{"id":4,"name":"Candy","balance":0},{"id":5,"name":"Phil","balance":18,"deposits":[100,18],"withdrawals":[100]}]

const r = bankAccounts.filter(({deposits:d=[],withdrawals:w=[],balance:b})=>
  Math.abs([...d, ...w.map(i=>-i), -b].reduce((a,b)=>a+b))>Number.EPSILON)

console.log(r)
```